# Why does it return 1?

Tags: c

Goal of program: return 1 if two arrays are identical. if not return 0.
What I did:

```
#include <stdio.h>


int identical ( int arr1[], int arr2[], unsigned int len )
{
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++){
        if (len == 0){
            return 1;
        } else if (arr1[i] != arr2[i]) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    }

}


int main ()
{
    int arr1[3] = {10,15,20};
    int arr2[3] = {10,15,21};
    printf("%d\n", identical(arr1, arr2, 3));

    return 0;
}
```

It always returns 1 and I cannot find the reason why.
What's wrong?

Comment: Hint: when do you think the `i++` in your `for` loop will ever happen?

Comment: Keep the return 1 outside the for loop and check if it's not equal inside the for loop and return 0.

Answer (score 2):

```
int identical ( int arr1[], int arr2[], unsigned int len )
{
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++){
     if (arr1[i] != arr2[i]) {
        return 0;
     }
   }
   return 1;
}
```

This only checks if 2 arrays have 3(len=3) similar values in a row.

Comment: The code you show is not limited to three array elements.

Comment: In his example it's 3.

Answer (score 1):

You have just messed up the if-else statements, as in the first iteration you are checking and also terminating the loop by using the return statement, so it never goes on the next index.

Just replace the `else` return statement with `continue` and at the end of the function add a return statement as, `return 1`

```
    int identical ( int arr1[], int arr2[], unsigned int len ){
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++){
        if (len == 0){
            return 1;
        } else if (arr1[i] != arr2[i]) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            continue;
        }
    }

    return 1;

}
```

**OR**

You need to rewrite function declaration as follows (in efficent way):

```
int identical ( int arr1[], int arr2[], unsigned int len ){

   if (len == 0)    return 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        if (arr1[i] != arr2[i])     return 0; 

   return 1;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: the `else continue` is redundant. as is the `if(len == 0)` since the loop will never be entered in that case

Comment: But the user might pass the parameter as 0 then we can have a check, and just rewrite the code in an efficient way by changing the logic, not the core. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>


int identical ( int arr1[], int arr2[], unsigned int len )
{
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++){
        if (len == 0){
            return 1;
        } else if (arr1[i] != arr2[i]) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            if (i == len - 1){
              return 1;      
            }
        }
    }

}


int main ()
{
    int arr1[3] = {10,15,20};
    int arr2[3] = {10,15,21};
    printf("%d\n", identical(arr1, arr2, 3));

    return 0;
}
```

The problem with your code is that, you're returning from the function before the loop gets to complete its iterations.